# Не работает обработчик событий

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть скрипт для страницы, который применяет методы fadeIn и fadeOut для некоторых блоков, при ширине окна браузера более 900 px. Проблема в том, что если окно растягивать, то необходимо перезагрузить страницу что бы скрипт сработал. Что бы он работал всегда, ввел обработчик событий addEventListener, но он не работает. Скрипт привязан к HTML в шапке страницы.

```js
$(document).ready(function funFade1(){

    if(window.innerWidth > 900) {
    $("#frosted_print").hover(
     function(){
         $("#gloss_print_back").fadeIn();
     },
     function() {
        $("#gloss_print_back").fadeOut();
    }
    )
    
    $("#gloss_print").hover(
     function(){
         $("#frosted_print_back").fadeIn();
     },
     function() {
        $("#frosted_print_back").fadeOut();
    }
    )
    } 
    
     window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
        funFade1;
     }, false);
    
})
```

Comment: обработчик работает, просто ты в нем функцию не вызываешь

Comment: мне кажется или тут смесь js и jQuery ?

Comment: да смесь, с технической части все плохо)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function (){

    $("#frosted_print").hover(
     function(){
       if(window.innerWidth > 900)
         $("#gloss_print_back").fadeIn();
     },
     function() {
       if(window.innerWidth > 900)
         $("#gloss_print_back").fadeOut();
     });

    $("#gloss_print").hover(
     function(){
       if(window.innerWidth > 900)
         $("#frosted_print_back").fadeIn();
     },
     function() {
       if(window.innerWidth > 900)
         $("#frosted_print_back").fadeOut();
    });
})
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогли)

Comment: @Ilya Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: Можно просто скрипт переместить в конец html-я, тогда `addEventListener` будет отрабатывать корректно

Comment: @Igor Отметил, еще раз спасибо